# Deleting tableView rows under condition and with UI clarification

Tags: ios

I need a method for allowing the user to delete a tableView row, only if a condition is met (if source == "MyApp"). I have provided an example below that works.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let source = objectSample[indexPath.row].source.name

    if source == "MyApp"{
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            let UUIDtoDelete = objectSample[indexPath.row].UUID
            deleteUUIDobject(UUIDtoDelete)
            objectSample.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

            println("Deleted")
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Not allowed to delete")
    }
}
```

The resulting UI is a bit confusing to the user, because it leaves all the rows with a red swipe to delete button, whether or not he/she can actually delete the row. So I tried to make the delete button grey if the condition was not met:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let source = objectSample[indexPath.row].source.name
    println(source)

    if source == "MyApp"{
        var deleteButtonRed = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            println("To delete is OK, set color red")
        })
        deleteButtonRed.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return [deleteButtonRed]
    }

    else{
        var deleteButtonGray = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            println("To delete is NOT OK, ret color gray")
        })
        deleteButtonGray.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return [deleteButtonGray]

        }

    return ["Will Never Happen"]
}
```

My problem is that these methods do not work together. For some reason commitEditingStyle is never evaluated if I apply the method editActionsForRowAtIndexPath. The row is not deleted even if source == "MyApp". How can I combine the two together?
Or is there a better way to show which tableView entries the user can/ cannot delete?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try the delegate method `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to prevent other cells from editing:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return source == "MyApp"
}
```

Or this to left other cells editable, but without remove control:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if source == "MyApp" {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's clever. Away from computer for a day or two, but I will test and get back to you as soon as I have time. Thank you, have a nice weekend.